# Complex type name - case insensitive

Tags: xsd

I have a complex type definition as follows:

```
<xs:complexType name="SqlQuery">
        <xs:all>
            <xs:element name="Connector" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xs:element name="Query" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
        </xs:all>
        <xs:attribute name="CommandTimeOut" type="xs:nonNegativeInteger"/>
</xs:complexType>
```

and an element definition as follows:

```
<xs:element name="SQLQuery" type="SqlQuery" />
```

I would like the element name="SQLQuery" to be case-insensitive so all of the "SQLQuery" combinations will be legal:
SQLQuery,
SqlQuery,
sqlquery etc.

Does any one know how to do that?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you please accept the answer if some answer helped you in any way?

Answer (score 0):

The only option I can think of is to use `xsd:choice` with all the possible combinations you would like to support. Why can't you just use sql-query as the element name? What is the point of providing all these alternatives?

Comment: Hi,
The point in providing all the alternatives is giving the users maximum freedom to write however they want. I dont want to give an error to a user that wrote "False" instead of "false".
Can you show me how can I use xs:choice in order to get that behavior?

Answer (score 0):

A bit hackish but you can convert your xml elements to lower case prior to validating with xsd schema.

Answer (score 0):

You should define substitutions. =)

```
<xs:element name="sqlquery" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="SQLQuery" substitutionGroup="sqlquery"/>
<xs:element name="SQLQUERY" substitutionGroup="sqlquery"/>
```